# How to add Hotkeys in a text editor?

Tags: python, wxpython

There is a simple text editor developed with WxPython.
I need to add hot keys. ctrl+1, ctrl+2, ctrl+3 and ctrl+4. So that when you press these hot keys to perform certain functions.
How can I do it?
The code:

```
import os
import wx
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title)
        self.textBox = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        menuOpen = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN,"O&pen","")
        menuExit = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT,"E&xit","")
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(fileMenu,"&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOpen, menuOpen)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, menuExit)
        self.Show(True)
    def OnOpen(self,e):
        self.dirName = ''
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a file", self.dirName, "", "text file|*.txt", wx.FD_OPEN)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.fileName = dlg.GetFilename()
            self.dirName = dlg.GetDirectory()
            f = open(os.path.join(self.dirName, self.fileName), 'r')
            self.textBox.SetValue(f.read())
            f.close()
        dlg.Destroy()
    def OnExit(self,e):
        self.Close(True)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MyFrame(None, 'RecordBooks')
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What you have tried so far? What was the result? Did you check the [wxpython wiki](https://wiki.wxpython.org/RegisterHotKey)?

Comment: if you have function in menu then you can assign shortcut in menu (so callled "accelerator") - ie. `"O&pen\tCtrl+1"` - and it will work without any other code. [Menu.Append](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Menu.html#wx.Menu.Append)

Comment: It's not for the menu. I need certain keys to trigger a code. This is an additional function of the program

Comment: see [wxPython: Keyboard Shortcuts (Accelerators)](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/12/02/wxpython-keyboard-shortcuts-accelerators/) but you will have to use `print()` instead of `print` and `wx.Window.NewControlId()` instead of `wx.NewId()`